# Adding ParseFile to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, image-uploading

```
private void savePicture() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("pic.png", stream.toByteArray());
    file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(GenerateReportActivity.this, 
                    "Couldn't save image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } else {
                try {
                    newItem.put("image", file);
                    myReports.put(newItem);
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    Utility.showMessage(ex.getMessage(), 
                        "JSON ERROR PICTURE", GenerateReportActivity.this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(null);
    imgTakenPhoto.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

In this method I'm trying to save an image I captured from Camera (currently saved saved as a Bitmap) and I want to add the image attribute to my JSONObject `newItem`. Then `newItem` is added to `myReports` which is a JSONArray. `myReports` is then put into my ParseObject under the key `"myReports"` and I call `saveInBackground()`. However, the problem is that when I look at the database, the JSONObject with the picture attribute is not showing.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the **request** object which is received on the server side?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: When you send a request from a client to a server via HTTP then you can actually see what data is received. Depended on what server software you use there will be a solution to inspect the data.

Comment: To do what @JJD is talking about, you need to set up Cloud Code. Then you can monitor what happens at `beforeSave` and `afterSave` for pic.png. My guess is that the file size is too large, as I recall col entries are limited to 128kb (except for ParseFile entries).

Comment: I think I would refactor to a solution where simply creating a pointer to the row holding your image, instead of the image itself in `myReports`